# How to access .net MVC ViewData from Jquery directly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am passing viewdata into my aspx page like so:

```
//Controller
List<user> userList = Data.GetAllUsersForCompany(companyId);
List<SelectListItem> dropDownList = FormatUserList(userList);
ViewData["UserList"] = userList;
ViewData["FormattedUserList"] = dropDownList;
return View();
```

I am populating a drop down with the name of a user, which I want to bind with Jquery so that when the user changes the drop down this in turn updates the input fields with the current selected user.

The ASPX page:

```
<p>
  <%= Html.DropDownList("userSelected", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["FormattedUserList"] )%><br /><br />

  <%= Html.TextBox("userFName")%><br />
  <%= Html.TextBox("userLName")%><br />    
  <%= Html.TextBox("userEmail")%>
</p>
```

I hook up Jquery to detect the drop-down changes which work, but how do I manipulate the input boxes with data?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#userSelected").change(function() {
      var pkUser = $("#userSelected").val();
      alert("Current UserID is " + pkUser); //works up to here just fine
      $("#userFName).val() = ViewData["UserList"].Select(x => x.pkUser == valueOfDropDown).fName; ???
      .
      .
      .
    });
  });
</script>
```

Am I doing things completely wrong? Can you point out what the best practice is for this scenario. If I can get away from having postbacks that would be ideal.

Soul (MVC newbie)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing your javascript and c#, remember that the javascript only executes client side, and the c# only executes server side. That being said, if you want to have some of your viewdata hanging around for your javascript to use on the client side, you need to encode it in the page somewhere the javascript can get at it. The easiest way I can think of is to use a JavaScriptSerializer and embed the values into your javascript, kind of like:

```
<%
  var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var users = <%= serializer.Serialize(ViewData["UserList"]) %>;

  //Use the users variable now with a copy of the view data.
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew fundamentally it was wrong merging the server code with the client side. I guess I was really hoping it would be possible with MVC.

Anyways thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it is better to have static javascript files. It's not universally the case, but its often very hard to manage code that's parsed together at runtime. So rather than trying to write serverside code in your script tags (like the line that seems to be breaking), you should try writing the data to a hidden part of the page, perhaps, and then getting that data with jQuery.

You should be able to output a hidden form element with the value of any data that you want to use later on.

Say your output was:

```
<input type="hidden" id="fname_store" name="fname" value="soul" />
```

This could also be a single variable that is set in an inline script if you find this method messy:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = <% serialized_data_from_the_server_side %>;
</script>
```

Then your line that breaks would be something like this:

```
$('#userFName').val($('#fname_store').val());
```

Notice that you are missing a quote in your code at the end of the selector, and also notice that the jQuery val() function is set by passing it a value, not setting it equal to a value.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can always update your Action.

```
List<user> userList = Data.GetAllUsersForCompany(companyId);
List<SelectListItem> dropDownList = FormatUserList(userList);

return Json(new { UserList = userList, FomattedUserList = dropDownList} );
```